# How to force Mac window to foreground?

Tags: c++, cocoa, macos, graphics, macos-carbon

How can I programmatically force a mac window to be the front window? I have the window handle, and want to ensure that my window is displayed above all other windows. I can use both Carbon & Cocoa for this.

Comment: Are you talking about a window in your own program? Or do you want to deal with other app's windows?

Comment: Raymond Chen wrote about this very problem, when he asked the important question: "What if two programs did this?" Once you realize that, you'll understand that never can _force_ this, only _request_ this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For Cocoa, you can set the window level using:

```
[window setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

A floating window will display above all other regular windows, even if your app isn't active.

If you want to make your app active, you can use:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

and

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can (32 bit only) use kOverlayWindowClass:

```
WindowRef carbon_window = NULL;
CreateNewWindow( kOverlayWindowClass , ... , &carbon_window );
// if you need cocoa:
NSWindow *cocoa_window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithWindowRef:carbon_window];
```

Otherwise create an NSWindow and set the window level to `kCGOverlayWindowLevel`.

Note that this will be above the dashboard as well.  If you want to be below the dashbord use kCGUtilityWindowLevel.