# background cocoa app/utility that displays full screen image at given time

Tags: cocoa, macos

I want to write an app for Mac OS X. The app/utility would act according to preset schedule. I will have different time intervals at which I want this app to show a certain image in full screen regarding if there are other apps running at the time.

The real question is how to check this time interval in the background and bring this app in-front and enter full screen. I know how to go full screen, but I am stuck at bringing this app in-front of all other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To schedule a method to be called after an interval, just use `NSTimer` and one of its `+scheduledTimer...` methods.

To force your application to be active, call `[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES]`.

If you want your window to appear above absolutely everything, including the screensaver, set its level to `NSScreenSaverWindowLevel + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes immediately to mind is use AppleScript, e.g. if you execute the following AppleScript from within your app:

```
tell application "MyBackgroundApp"
  activate
end tell
```

There is an [Apple Tech Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2006/tn2084.html) with sample code for sending AppleScript from a Cocoa app using `NSAppleScript`.

Comment: Good idea. Might be the right approach. I wasn't thinking of using apple script within my app... I guess when my background app get's activated it gets some kind of notification which I can use to go full screen then...?

Comment: @Primoz: for Carbon apps I know there is an activate event when your app gets moved to the foreground - I assume there's something similar for Cocoa apps but I'm not really an expert in this area.

Comment: sure Paul no problem. I will figure this out, I'm pretty sure my self app gets notified about this kind of change. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[How to force Mac window to foreground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763827/how-to-force-mac-window-to-foreground/2767236#2767236)